# Entities are loaded from the database when FetchType is set to LAZY

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I had to change the fetchtype from EAGER to LAZY in some classes to prevent Hibernate from loading all the associated entities but changing the fetchtype does not seem to work and the entities are still loaded like before. I have also seen that Hibernate runs a SELECT first to load all the Documents and then one separate SELECT for each related Profile if they are different. Depends on if some of the Documents are related to the same Profile or not. So if I have 10 Documents with different Profiles then Hibernate will run 11 SELECT query. I'm not sure if it's normal behaviour.

I have tried setting the fetchtype to LAZY on both sides, even to remove the relation on Profile side.

```
public class Profile {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "profile", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
private List<Document> documents;
```

```
public abstract class Document {

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinColumn(name = "profile_id")
private Profile profile;
```

```
  EntityManager em = _emf.createEntityManager();
try {
  Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM Document d ORDER BY d.id DESC");
  List<Document> documents = query.getResultList();
  return documents;
} finally {
  em.close();
}
```

I want Hibernate to load only the Documents from the database without the related Profiles.

Comment: I assume that your `Document document` is really `Profile profile`. In this case, you might want to set `optional = false` on the `@ManyToOne`.  This is necessary because Hibernate must set the field `document` during fetching, either null, a proxy, or an object. With the default `optional = true`, Hibernate can not rule out the null case and can therefore not set a non-null proxy required for lazy loading.

Comment: @halfbit Thanks for catching that. I have tried `optional = false` but it didn't help. Strange thing is if I set `FetchType.LAZY` and try to access the profile after I close the entity manager then it says: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role ...

Comment: "lazy loading" doesn't mean "no loading". It means that the association is loaded lazily, i.e. the first time you access the collection (call any of its methods).